# My rake executable is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rvm

I've been using RVM and created a rails app when I realized that my `rake` command doesn't do anything.

`which rake` gives:

```
/home/jmu303/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rake
```

but when viewing the source code, `rake` is a completely empty file!

`gem install rake` didn't do anything (should it have?)

My gemfile has `gem 'rake', '~> 10.3.2'`.

Is there some type of symlink I need to make or something?

`gem pristine rake` gives (and this error message is now occuring after `gem install rake` as well):

```
Restoring gems to pristine condition...
Skipped rake-10.1.0, it is a default gem
Restored rake-10.2.2
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    invalid gem: package metadata is missing in /home/jmu303/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/cache/rake-10.3.2.gem
```

Comment: Does `bundle exec rake <command>` work?

Comment: @pdobb nothing, returns no output.

Comment: Try doing `gem pristine rake` to see if that resets the gem source.

Comment: @pdobb error message in edit.

Comment: I've seen this before. I had to delete the folder manually and then reinstall the gem to get the `pristine` command to work. Try that and `bundle` again and see where that gets you.

Comment: @pdobb which folder specifically? thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54319/discussion-between-pdobb-and-jesse-mu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `rake` gem source somehow got corrupted. The way to fix is to attempt to refresh the source with:

```
gem pristine rake
```

When doing this you may get a invalid gem error. In which case, you'll need to manually delete the source folder that it complains about. Then just re-run `bundle` and try running the `rake` command again.